# step response data extraction from response data of a model(simulink)?

Tags: control, matlab, pid-controller, step-response

I want to design a PID controller with the step response method, so I needed to save the step response of my model in simulink in workspace (Vout) with saved format :structure wih time, I exctracted the time value by using 
the command

```
t=Vout.time
```

and signal value as:

```
y=Vout.signals
```

then run the command to exctract the data to matlab:

```
load StepInfoData t y
```

so I can analyse it by calling the function `plot(t,y)` and `S1 = stepinfo(y,t,0.4)`
but it shows the error following

Warning: Variable 'y' not found.

Warning: Variable 't' not found.

and the same for plot function. actually, I am not sure if the workspace is the correct method to save the data.
link:https://se.mathworks.com/help/control/ref/stepinfo.html#mw_cab22a5a-b8ef-49fd-b071-3e7888430c00
the model looks like:[image]
thanks

Comment: You should use the "To Workspace" block in simulink. I believe you misunderstood the example given.

Comment: I used exactly "to workspace"  and changed the t and y to other variable like a and b and still not working.(i edited the post)

Comment: But then why do you use "load StepInfoData t y"? You just need to run the simulation and plot the data. plot(Vout) should do the trick.

Comment: I used because in he link it say you save the data then call the commands "load StepInfoData t y". I runt the commant now Plot(Vout) and shows this error:>> plot(Vout)
Error using plot
Not enough input arguments.

Comment: Use the "Timeseries" option instead of "Structure with time". It works fine with Timeseries, just tested. Also, that "load ..." line in the link is particular to that example, it makes no sense in your context.

Comment: the plot(Vout) works for timeseries, I used the same command from that example but I tried to assign  time and values to them so I could use them directly. nevertheless, I tried with changing the names to a and b, I needed to sperate time value from signal value. with timeseries i cannot use the fnctionality of stepinfo:>> S1 = stepinfo(Vout,0.015)
Undefined function 'isfinite' for input arguments of type 'timeseries'. i tried with name of my model as well but provide wrong result

Comment: and >> b=Vout.signals;
No appropriate method, property, or field 'signals' for class 'timeseries'.

Comment: Just use "y = Vout.Data" and "t = Vout.Time".

Comment: thanks, Vicente Cunha, it worked, I want to make this question as answered but I cannot find where?

Comment: I will write up an answer and you can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To export signals from simulink to the matlab workspace, use the "To Workspace" block. One of the more relevant options of the block is the specification of format of the exported variable. When using the Timeseries format to export a variable named *simout*, data can be plotted using:

```
plot(simout)
```

To retrieve data and time arrays from Timeseries into separate variables, use:

```
data = simout.Data
time = simout.Time
```